# Positive to negative infinity integration

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^{-x^2} dx$$

I guess let $u = -x^2$ , hence $\frac{du}{dx}=-2x$

$$dx = \frac{-1}{2x}du$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{u}}{2} du$$

this is where i get lost

Comment: When you do substitution, the limits of integration change as well. In this case, you're not supposed to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty du$, but $\int_\infty^\infty du$ (as $x$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, $u$ goes from $\infty$ to $\infty$).

Comment: @Arthur OK, so you claim that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{x^2}\,dx=0$.

Comment: yes he does, because it's obvious

Comment: $e^{-x^2} \rightarrow 0$, when $x \rightarrow +-\infty$. If I call your integral I:

$I=[-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2}]_{-\infty}^{+\infty} = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Also you could use;
\begin{equation}
\frac{d (e^{-x^{2}})}{dx} = -2xe^{-x^{2}}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

When you have a “doubly improper” integral, you *must* split it into two integrals (or do a double limit). Thus
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-x^2}\,dx=
\int_{-\infty}^a xe^{-x^2}\,dx+
\int_a^\infty xe^{-x^2}\,dx
$$
where you can choose $a$ arbitrarily. In this case, a good choice is $a=0$, because in the first integral you can make the substitution $x=-t$ that produces
$$
\int_{\infty}^0 te^{-t^2}\,dt+
\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2}\,dx
$$
Now, the second one is a converging integral and the first one is its opposite, so the result is zero.

Beware that simply reasoning by “the function is odd” can lead to wrong results: the function $f(x)=xe^{x^2}$ is odd, but
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{x^2}\,dx
$$
doesn't exist in the sense of improper integrals; there is a “principal value integral”, but it's a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is odd. So when you integrate all over the real axis ($(-\infty,\infty)$) all the areas cancel each other out. Even if you don't notice that, after the substitution your limits of integration change to $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty}$ and $\int_a^a f(x) \mathrm{d}x$ is always $0$.

Comment: Would you say the same if $f(x)=xe^{x^2}$?

Comment: @egreg No, it does not converge. It's Cauchy's PV is 0.

Comment: Principal value is not the same as improper integral.